# Display Image in ajax response in a table

Tags: ajax, image, laravel, display

I am working on a laravel project.I have uploaded image using ajax in database and to the local "public/images" folder as well.But i can not show the image without refreshing my page.Some mistake in response success function.Can anyone help me out?

```
success:function(data)
            {
                $('.error').remove();
                $('#table').append("<tr class='post" + data.id + "'>"+
                    "<td>" + data.id + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.name + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.bank_name  + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.bankbranch_location + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.image + "</td>"+
                    "<td>" + data.created_at + "</td>"+
                    "<td><button class='show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-bank_id='" + data.bank_name + "' data-bankbranch_id='" + data.bankbranch_location + "' data-name='" + data.name + "' data-phone='" + data.phone + "'><span class='fa fa-eye'></span></button> <button class='edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-bank_id='" + data.bank_name + "' data-bankbranch_id='" + data.bankbranch_location + "' data-name='" + data.name + "' data-phone='" + data.phone + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-bank_id='" + data.bank_name + "' data-bankbranch_id='" + data.bankbranch_location + "' data-name='" + data.name + "' data-phone='" + data.phone + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></td>"+
                    "</tr>");
            }
```

Comment: if you want to display the image without refreshing your page, you can refresh your table..  So, after you add new data or update the data, you can refresh your table

Comment: Hi.My other added data comes without refreshing page because i am using ajax.I haven't been able to put the image source in in the ajax response function.i am not sure about  how to do it.

Comment: Can you tell us what `data` contains? Where is it coming from? You could do a `console.log` of it inside the success function to confirm that the correct data, as you expect it, is present.

Comment: does your image appear after you reload the page? or you can't get your image?

Comment: Before i reload my page only image name appears that comes from the database. eg:"something.jpg"
But after reloading the page the image itself appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you res you should use  show image

```
success:function(data)
{
    $('.error').remove();
    let html = `
    <tr class='post${data.id}'>
        <td>${data.id}</td>
        <td>${data.name}</td>
        <td>${data.bank_name}</td>
        <td><img src="path/to/${data.image}" alt=""></td>
        <td>${data.created_at}</td>
        <td>
          <div data-id='${data.id}' data-bank_id='${data.bank_name}' data-bankbranch_id='${data.bankbranch_location}' 
                  data-name='${data.name}' data-phone='${data.phone}'>
              <button class='show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm'> <span class='fa fa-eye'></span> </button>
              <button class='edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button>
              <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr> `;

    $('#table').append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my controller from where the data is saved in database and in a local folder called "images" and giving a response to the ajax function with these datas

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
      ]);


      if ($validator->passes()) {


        $input = $request->all();
        $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);



       $employee= Employee::create($input);


        return response()->json($employee);
      }


      return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the `data.image` inside the `src` attribute  of `image` tag.

`"<td>" + <img src='/yourpath/' + data.image + "> </td>"`

For Public path in Laravel use:

`"<td>" + <img src='{{ URL::asset('images/') }}' +'/' + data.image + "> </td>"`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <